# Access denied for 'root'@'%' when loading files from my computer

Tags: mysql, command-prompt

I've logged in and accessed my database and can insert data manually into my newly created table but when I try load a .csv file from my desktop I get the error: "Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)

I'm assuming this means I don't have access to my own files or something? Really stuck.

Comment: does the mysql user account have access to your desktop folder? the account you log into mysql with has **NOTHING** to do with system-level login accounts.

Comment: What OS are you using

Comment: Windows 7, and not sure if the mysql account has access to my desktop

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that user *root@%* is different from user *root@localhost*.  I'm assuming that you are accessing the server locally, then trying to gain access from your desktop machine.

You will need to grant access to your desktop machine using the [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) command.

i.e.

> grant all on * . * to 'root'@'%' identified by 'password'

Comment: Also note, it is probably a bad idea to have a root user that has the ability to log in from anywhere.

Comment: I'm just making a dummy database to play around with for another project but I've done this before and never had a problem loading my own files. Which password would go in that slot?

Comment: Still saying access denied